# MySQL left join COUNT() and SUM() with CASE from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, sum

I have the following tables in a succession of 1-to-many relationships:

company_company, company_portfolio, building_site and statistics_meter. The area of difficulty I am having is the final table, statistics_meter.

For the benefit of this exercise, it's structure is as follows:

Records are related within the same table, with some being parent meters, and some being child meters. Where a record is a child, it will have parent_meter_id set, and building_id, which crucially, is how the table is LEFT JOIN'ed set to NULL.

```
 id  | parent_meter_id | site_ref            | building_id
 1   | NULL            | some building       | 45
 2   | NULL            | some other building | 45
 3   | 1               | and another         | NULL
 4   | 1               | one another one     | NULL
 5   | 2               | final one           | NULL
```

I have two requirements:

1 - count the number of parent meters where the building_id is set (which I am doing successfully)

2 - count the number of meters where the parent_meter_id matches the meter_id of those counted in (1)

Thus I would expect a result whereby (1) = 2 and (2) = 3.

Here is the SQL I've got so far...I tried fiddling around with a SUM case when but I think it's totally wrong. Is this even possible within one query?

Thanks for the help.

```
        SELECT
        building_site.id as site_id,
        building_site.site_ref as building_name,
        COUNT(statistics_meter.id) AS meter_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN statistics_meter.parent_meter_id = [???] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS check_meter_count
        FROM company_company
        LEFT JOIN company_portfolio ON company_portfolio.company_id=company_company.id
        LEFT JOIN building_site ON building_site.portfolio_id=company_portfolio.id
        LEFT JOIN statistics_meter ON statistics_meter.building_id=building_site.id
        WHERE company_company.id=41
        GROUP BY building_site.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but in the end I performed a left join and subquery as below and performed two counts, one COUNT() for total number to answer my requirement (2) and a COUNT(distinct) to answer my requirement (1)

```
        SELECT
        count(distinct statistics_meter.id) as meter_count,
        count(statistics_meter.id) as check_meter_count
        FROM company_company
        LEFT JOIN company_portfolio ON company_portfolio.company_id=company_company.id
        LEFT JOIN building_site ON building_site.portfolio_id=company_portfolio.id
        LEFT JOIN statistics_meter ON statistics_meter.building_id=building_site.id
        LEFT JOIN (select * from statistics_meter where parent_meter_id is not NULL) sm2 on sm2.parent_meter_id = statistics_meter.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understand you, you'll need to use a subquery to get the parent meters with a building id, and then join that to your main table.
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aec24/6)

```
select
sm.id,
sm.parent_meter_id,
sm2.id as ID2,
sm.site_ref,
sm.building_id
from
statistics_meter sm
inner join (
  select
  id,
  parent_meter_id
  from
  statistics_meter
  where
  building_id is not null) sm2
  on sm.parent_meter_id = sm2.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my question I specified that I need two different counts for the result .. can I use count with this subquery solution?

Comment: I don't see why not. What exactly are you trying to count?

Comment: I put it in the question. Here it is for ease: I have two requirements:

1 - count the number of parent meters where the building_id is set (which I am doing successfully)

2 - count the number of meters where the parent_meter_id matches the meter_id of those counted in (1)

Comment: Thanks, close to what I am looking for. But I am looking to fulfil BOTH of my requirements in the SAME query and get two counts back..e.g. from the sample data, get a count result of "2" for those where building id=45 and get a count result of "3" for it's child meters (you have done the latter correctly in your last SQL Fiddle). Appreciate your help.

Comment: OK, i actually sorted this myself, see my answer.